# Maxtrix - How to move columns to rows

Tags: powerbi

I have a Maxtrix that looks as follows:

[image]

And the Visualizations pane looks as follows:

[image]

Sales, COGS, GP and GP% are fields in a dataset. The YearMonth field is a field from another dataset.

What I want is for Sales, COGS, GP and GP% to be rows and my only column should be year-month. So I would have a row for Sales and totals for each year and month. And then another row for COGS and totals for each year and month etc. I can't find an easy way to do this because Sales, COGS, GP etc. are not like categories contained in another dataset, linked to this dataset that I could drag to Rows in the Visualization tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting for this. Go to the Format tab and turn on 'Show on rows' under the Values section.

[image: Show on rows]

Comment: Fan freakin' tastic. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would first create a table using Enter Data e.g. **All Measures** containing 1 column (e.g. **Measure Name**) and 4 rows, containing Sales , COGS , GP, GP%.

Then I would create a Measure using the SWITCH function, e.g.

```
Any Measure = SWITCH ( 'All Measures'[Measure Name] , "Sales" , [Sales] ,"COGS", [COGS] , "GP" , [GP] , "GP%" , [GP%] )
```

Then I would add 'All Measures'[Measure Name] to the **Rows** well, and replace the **Values** well with **Any Measure**.

You may need to enhance that to get the numeric formats right, e.g. by wrapping each measure reference in a FORMAT function.